# regular expression : get super scripted text

Tags: regex

I would like to get super scripted text via following html string.

```
testing to <sup>supers</sup>cript o<sup>n</sup>e
```

The result I would like to get is like below

```
supers
n
```

[This is what I tried right now](http://regex101.com/r/cK6sT6/2)

But the result is not what I want.

```
<sup>supers
<sup>n
```

Could anyone give me suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if there may be other HTML tags between `<sup>` and `</sup>`:

```
(?<=<sup>)(.*?)(?=<\/sup>)
```

[Check the demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV3lH3/2).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lookbehind` in your regex:

```
(?<=<sup>)[^<]*
```

#### [Update Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cK6sT6/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=<sup>)([^<]*?)(?=<\/)
```

This should work.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/13

Answer (score 1):

You were close, just not capturing your match:

[Updated regex](http://regex101.com/r/cK6sT6/4)

`(?:<sup>)([^<]*)` I just added a capture group around your match